# Hiding Titlebar in NSWindow, rounding the corners and keeping the shadow

Tags: cocoa

I like the way the developers behind Vox.app have created a custom titlebar and still kept the original shadow.

If you set the styleMask = NSBorderlessWindowMask it will create another kind of shadow, and the rounded corners are gone.

And it doesn't seem to be that easy to recreate those shadows especially when you also want rounded corners.

I have taken a window shot of the app that I like. Look at the drop shadows and the title bar.

Is it possible (I assume) to do this? And if so, how?

[image: Vox app. I am interested in how to create the shadow and title bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible (I assume) to do this?

Yes, this is possible.

> And if so, how?

You need to subclass the `NSWindow` and `NSView`, set the background color, use custom buttons etc.

For curvy-corners, you need to draw using bezier path. I tried reached somewhat near, however titlebar's color is not changed in this screenshot... but I hope you can do it from here:

[image]

Comment: The last line, is what I have the most difficulties achieving.

Comment: I managed to remove the titlebar :) I will post the code later.

Comment: @Chrene: thats great :)